# My jQuery code doesn't seem to be affecting my web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried using the google api and my own jQuery.js file, and I'm checked it through a lot and my javascript code seems to be good, so I'm guessing it's something obvious between linking jQuery to the web page that I'm missing

[Here's the code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzE4M/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>COMPUTERS.</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cstyle.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navhead" align="center">
            <div id="navleft" class="nav">
                <p class="valign">Copyright and Patents</p>
            </div>
            <div id="navcentre" class="nav" align="center">
                <p class="valign">Computer Misuse</p>
            </div>
            <div id="navright" class="nav">
                <p class="valign">Data Protection</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    });
    $(".nav").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
    });
});
```

Comment: It [seems to be working](http://jsfiddle.net/hzE4M/1/) after including the jQuery file in the **Frameworks & Extensions**

Comment: You haven't included the call to jquery, whether that's on your local drive, or a CDN.

Comment: I added jQuery 1.9.1 in Frameworks & Extensions, and it seems to work, as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the jquery.js

Include that in your file to work..

Add this line before your js

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hzE4M/2/

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in JSFiddle. It works.

```
$(".nav").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
});
$(".nav").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_Zhe_Han/EmJZQ/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <head>
        <title>COMPUTERS.</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cstyle.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cscript.js"></script>
    </head>
```

your code is ok .just add this line.